# Finding the value of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $S$ be the disk $|z|<3$, in the complex plane and $f:S\to\Bbb{C}$
>   be an analytic function such that
>   $$f\Big(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}ni\Big)=-\frac2{n^2}$$ for each natural
>   number $n$. Find the value of $f(\sqrt{2})$.

We can see that $1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}ni\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence the function $g(z)=f(z)+(Im(z))^2$ has a sequence of zeros with an accumulation point in $S$. If $g(z)$ were analytic we could have deduced from this that $g(z)$ is identically zero in $S$. But $f(z)$ is analytic doesn't imply $g(z)$ is analytic. What should be done? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $f(z)$ coincides with $g(z) = (z-1)^2$ on the points $z_n=1+i\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$, i.e. $$f(z_n)=g(z_n)$$

Comment: Perfect. That was too easy. Why didn't I notice. Thanks.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha You had the right idea: This function looks close to $z\rightarrow z^2$. After I thought, okay if $1$ was missing from $f$'s argument it would be $z^2$, wait a minute! translations do not affect analyticity; how about (z-1)^2 then.